# change ajax method jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

is this possible to change ajax method from "GET" to "POST" from this plugin [jquery Autocomplete](https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: you need to modify your jquery autocomplete code file

Answer (score 1):

readind the [code](https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js) bellow from your plugin in line 576 i fonud this "fetchRemoteData" method, wich is called directly by ajax. Could be this helps you?

Comment: im still newbie, how to implement it? can you help me?

Comment: as i seen in more detail, the plugin didnt suppor "method" in the line i put behid http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#method, try to put a revision in the github of the author, for passing a method.

Comment: why is necessary to use get?, could you try to use post with query params?

Comment: yeah, i want to post with custom param

Comment: the look at the implementation of the plugin with $.ajax, i think it was done

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({ 
   source: function (request, response) {
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"YourPhpPage.php",
          data: request,
          dataType: 'json'
      });
   }
}, {minLength: 3 });
```

Comment: this plugin not jquery.ui.autocomplete but from this
https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete

Comment: yeah i know but did you try what i answered here ?

Comment: i have try, TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function